# ASP.NET Core 2 - develop using custom domain names and ssl using IISExpress

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I want to be able to develop locally using a custom domain and ssl rather than localhost.

How can I setup a custom domain + ssl in VS Solution instead of localhost?

Answer (score 7):

### Simple Setup - Using Server URLs

If you want to associate your server to use all the IP addresses assigned to the server/web host then you can do this:

```
var host = new WebHostBuilder()
    .UseUrls("http://*:80", "http://localhost")
    .UseKestrel()
    .UseIISIntegration()
    .Build();
```

*Note: If you don't want all IP addresses, then you can change from `http://*` to a specific IP address such as `http://111.111.111.111`*. Also, the port is not a requirement, but I have used it for completeness of the answer. **It's also important to note that SSL won't work with** `UseUrls`

*There is a great amount of additional detail that you can find over at the official Microsoft Docs about Server URLs [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/hosting?tabs=aspnetcore2x#server-urls).*

---

### Binding SSL Certifications (Kestrel Only) -- Endpoint Configuration

> Please note that hosting over a **public** endpoint via Kestrel (even with SSL) is not recommended and you should use a reverse proxy like Nginx or IIS. You can read more about it from the [official Microsoft Docs here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x#when-to-use-kestrel-with-a-reverse-proxy).

You didn't mention if you were using Kestrel or not, but I will assume you are... In which case, you can configure an SSL certificate easily by binding sockets using the options.

Here is an example of using TCP sockets using the `Listen` method:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    BuildWebHost(args).Run();
}

public static IWebHost BuildWebHost(string[] args) =>
    WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .UseStartup<Startup>()
        .UseKestrel(options =>
        {
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5000);
            options.Listen(IPAddress.Loopback, 5001, listenOptions =>
            {
                listenOptions.UseHttps("testCert.pfx", "testPassword");
            });
        })
        .UseIISIntegration() // <-- don't forget you will need this for IIS!
        .Build();
```

Note: That if you use both the `Listen` method and `UseUrls`, the `Listen` endpoints override the `UseUrls` endpoints.

*You can find more info [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/kestrel?tabs=aspnetcore2x#endpoint-configuration) at the official Microsoft Docs.*

---

### Configuring IISExpress

**Using the GUI**
You can right-click the project and click [Properties].

[image]

**Using launchSettings.json.**
You have to configure this using the `launchSettings.json` which you can find here:

[image: launchSettings.json]

```
"iisSettings": {
  "windowsAuthentication": false,
  "anonymousAuthentication": true,
  "iisExpress": {
    "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:61471/",
    "sslPort": 44360
  }
},
"profiles": {
  "IIS Express": {
  "commandName": "IISExpress",
  "launchBrowser": true,
  "launchUrl": "https://localhost:44360",
  "environmentVariables": {
    "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
  }
}
```

---

### Configuring IIS Endpoints

If you use IIS, the URL bindings for IIS override any bindings that you set by calling either `Listen` or `UseUrls`. For more information, see [Introduction to ASP.NET Core Module](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/servers/aspnet-core-module?tabs=aspnetcore2x).

Comment: ooh, haven't seen that before, will have a look.

Comment: Hosting Kestrel SSL for development is pretty much okay. Kestrel only shouldn't be used as internet facing server (IFS), since that's what the quote from above is about. Also please note, that the launchSettings.json shouldn't be edited manually. Use the project properties -> Debug UI for that. Editing the launchsettings.json can result that the settings are not applied to IISExpress configs (in .vs/config/applicationhost.config file)

Comment: @Tseng - I didn't know about not editing the `launchSettings.json` is that a bug? Regardless, always great to get your input.

Comment: I wouldn't consider it a bug. The file is typically created by that UI and it keeps IIS setttings in sync with `.vs/config/applicationhost.config`. Only changing the port in `launchsettings.json` (at least in the past) resulted in only changed startup url, but the application still running on old port, because the `applicationhost.config` wasn't updated. Doing it via UI would update both files in the past.

Comment: SUPER IMPORTANT: Your port for SSL in IISExpress must be in the range 44300-44399. Your original answer had 443 shown for the sslPort, but your image showed a port of 44360. Oddly you can't edit this port in the properties page as far as I can see. Anyway I edited your answer to match the port in your image in the launchsettings.json (from 443 -> 44360)

Answer (score 2):

For .net core, to setup a custom domain:

1. Add domain to the hosts file, something like [www.yourapp.local](http://www.yourapp.local)
2. find the solution /.vs/applicationhost.config
   Add binding e.g.:
3. In the web project properties > Debug add the App Url to "http://www.yourapp.local:51791/"

(replace port number as required)

For SSL, I assume you can set the above bindings and settings to https and in the web app properties > Debug tick the "Enable SSL" checkbox.

also see this answer: [How to enable SSL for IIS Express in VS2015](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28933671/how-to-enable-ssl-for-iis-express-in-vs2015)

Answer (score 1):

If you're fine with the certificate validation error in your browser (or whatever client you use), you can put an entry in your *hosts* file:

`www.yourcustomdomain.com    127.0.0.1` (or `::1` if you're on IPv6)

and then use the custom domain to reach your web site locally.

In Windows the hosts file is usually located at *C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc*.

Answer (score 0):

First, add an entry in the client's `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` text file.  Follow instructions in the `hosts` file itself.

By "develop locally" do you mean on the local machine or local network?  If the latter, you must complete the following tasks (in any order).

- Generate as described [here](https://www.oshyn.com/blogs/2017/november/how-to-create-self-signed-certificates-in-windows-10) and configure as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38953547) a certificate on the server, and install it on the client.
- Configure the firewall to allow access to your web API as described [here](https://blog.kloud.com.au/2017/02/27/remote-access-to-local-aspnet-core-apps-from-mobile-devices/).
- Bind your web API to a non-`localhost` URL as described [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/28/External-Network-Access-to-Kestrel-and-IIS-Express-in-ASPNET-Core#exposing-iis-express-to-the-network) and [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.applicationhost/sites/site/bindings/binding).

I'm not sure off hand, but to get it working with IIS Express you might also need to run `netsh http add urlacl` as described [here](https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2016/Sep/28/External-Network-Access-to-Kestrel-and-IIS-Express-in-ASPNET-Core#exposing-iis-express-to-the-network) and [here](https://www.hanselman.com/blog/WorkingWithSSLAtDevelopmentTimeIsEasierWithIISExpress.aspx).

Some of the above links are specific to IIS Express since that's what you asked about.  If using Kestrel, then vary the above tasks as follows.

To configure your certificate on the server, add this to `appsettings.json`:

```
"Kestrel": {
    "Certificates": {
        "Default": {
            "Subject": "api.mycustomdomain.com",
            "Store": "My",
            "AllowInvalid": true
        }
    }
}
```

To bind your web API to a non-`localhost` URL, in `launchSettings.json`'s Kestrel profile, replace the `localhost` part of `applicationUrl`'s value with `0.0.0.0`.